# Execution failed ':share_plus:compileReleaseKotlin' in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, kotlin, dart

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':share_plus:compileReleaseKotlin'.

> Compilation error. See log for more details

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Answer (score 1):

Go to your build.gradle file in the root of your Android directory and upgrade your Kotlin_version to the latest. Current last version of kotlin is 1.6.21

so it should look like this:

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.21'
```

Comment: Already done, but not working.